# Installation of YouCompleteMe

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I have been trying to install `YouCompleteMe` for a long time. At first, I failed because I need to build `Vim` having python support. Now I have it solved, but I always fail at building `YouCompleteMe` itself because of various kinds of problems (if you guys want to help me on this, that's okay too :-)). The build log of `YouCompleteMe` is this (using only `./install.py`):

```
./install.py
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.1
...... Successful Detects ......
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Your C++ compiler supports C++11, compiling in that mode.
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a (found suitable version "2.7.10", minimum required is "2.6") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.10", minimum required is "2.6") 
NOT using libclang, no semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC will be available
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.10") 
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/ycm_build.jmI4vO
Scanning dependencies of target BoostParts
[  0%] [  2%] [  2%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp.o
...... Successfully Builds ......
[ 92%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o
In file included from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/type_traits/ice.hpp:15:0,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/python/detail/def_helper.hpp:9,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/python/class.hpp:29,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/PythonSupport.h:21,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/ycm_client_support.cpp:19:
/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_or.hpp:17:71: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_or.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_or.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                       ^
...... Some similar messages ......
In file included from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/type_traits/ice.hpp:18:0,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/python/detail/def_helper.hpp:9,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/python/class.hpp:29,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/PythonSupport.h:21,
                 from /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/ycm_core.cpp:19:
/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp:17:71: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_eq.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_eq.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                       ^
[ 96%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/CustomAssert.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/Result.cpp.o
[ 98%] [100%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CustomAssert.cpp.o
Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_client_support.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/build.make:387: recipe for target '/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_client_support.so' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_client_support.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:130: recipe for target 'ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX shared library /home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/build.make:387: recipe for target '/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:165: recipe for target 'ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:209: recipe for target 'ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_support_libs.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_support_libs.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:148: recipe for target 'ycm_support_libs' failed
make: *** [ycm_support_libs] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 372, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 361, in Main
    BuildYcmdLibs( args )
  File "/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py", line 275, in BuildYcmdLibs
    subprocess.check_call( build_command )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'ycm_support_libs', '--', '-j', '4']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./install.py", line 32, in <module>
    Main()
  File "./install.py", line 21, in Main
    subprocess.check_call( [ python_binary, build_file ] + sys.argv[1:] )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '/home/bunny/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

. So I install the package `vim-youcompleteme` by `apt` successfully. So how can I use `YouCompleteMe` now?

***EDIT:*** I used `vam` to install `YouCompleteMe`, no problem, but when I open `vi`, it gives me this error:

```
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..    <SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
  File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 34, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
    from ycm.client.ycmd_keepalive import YcmdKeepalive
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
  File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/client/ycmd_keepalive.py", line 22, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
from ycm.client.base_request import BaseRequest
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
   File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 20, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
    import requests
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>30_SetUpPython:
line   29:
ImportError: No module named requests
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

`vi --version` output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb 11 2016 19:19:30)
Compiled by Vostro-3400
Normal version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic          +file_in_path    -mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           -mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
+builtin_terms   -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    -keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        -langmap         +printer         +visual
-conceal         +libcall         -profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
-cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             -rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
-emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            -mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    
-farsi           -mouse_netterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: What's in your .vimrc? And what problems do you have with building youcompleteme? Installing vim-youcomplete via package has been asked previously, here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/541737/how-to-use-vim-youcompleteme

Comment: The installation was good. But when I open vi, it jumps out many errs, all about `youcompleteme#enable()`

Comment: You will need to copy and paste the *full* error message you get. Without it, no one can give you any meaningful information. Don't put it in the comments, you can edit your question.

Comment: Please add the information to the question. The info is crucial for anyone to answer the question, and thus you should not simply link to pastebins. If you want people to take the time to help you, then the least you can do is take the time to both formulate and formate your question to make it easy for people to understand what your problem is.

Comment: Please show `:version` output

Comment: If you used apt, you are on a Debian based distribution. Which means `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` is python built from source. That can lead to any number of python problems. Why do you have it?

Comment: @muru Can I redirect it so that it uses library from `/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`?

Comment: @Chromium telling it to use `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/usr/local/bin/python` is one way. But why do you have it? It will only cause more pain going forward. If you want a newer Python version, use the deadsnakes PPA, or use virualenvs

Comment: @muru So where is the problem located? Is my python build (some people say that in their builds), or is there something wrong with my dependencies?

Comment: @Chromium if YCM had some python dependencies, then installing using apt will install those - for the system python. The locally installed python would be unaware of these, and you'll have to install them separately for the local python as well, using pip, perhaps.

Comment: @muru install what separately? and I don't even know there is another python installation.

Comment: Whichever python dependencies YCM may have.

Comment: The second error is: `ImportError: No module named requests`. This can be fixed by installing `python-requests`.

Comment: You can use `apt-get`, or `pip`. "There is error" is still not something anyone can provide any meaningful answer to.

Comment: `apt` says that the `python-requests` is the newest version. and I figure out the problem. `python3` can import `requests` with no problem, but in `python2` (or `python`), there is an `ImportError`. I also use `pip`, it says that the package is up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tries, I finally find out what's going on with my installation of `vim-youcompleteme`, and I decided to answer my own question.

First, building from source is not a good idea, unless you *have* to do it (just like my non-python support `vim`). Installing pre-built packages is always a good idea and a good starting point.

Second, the dependencies are important. When having the package installed and plugin installed by `vam`(`vim-addon-manager`), you need to solve the problems showing on the start of `vim`. For me, the main problem is the `requests` and `requests_futures`. After figuring it out, just use `pip` to install it and done!

By the way, thank you for those guys have helped me! You guys give some good advice and hints!